# How to use multiple SELECTs within a single INSERT?

Tags: postgresql, select, bulk-insert

I'm currently working with PostgresSQL 13.3 and I thought I could have a file with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO points (zone_id, element_id, position_id) VALUES
    (SELECT zones._id, elements._id, positions._id FROM zones, elements, positions WHERE zones.name = 'A' AND elements.name = 'abc' AND positions.name = 'xyz'),
    (SELECT zones._id, elements._id, positions._id FROM zones, elements, positions WHERE zones.name = 'B' AND elements.name = 'bcd' AND positions.name = 'yza');
```

That doesn't work but I can bulk-insert using:

```
INSERT INTO points (zone_id, element_id, position_id) SELECT zones._id, elements._id, positions._id FROM zones, elements, positions WHERE zones.name = 'A' AND elements.name = 'abc' AND positions.name = 'xyz';
INSERT INTO points (zone_id, element_id, position_id) SELECT zones._id, elements._id, positions._id FROM zones, elements, positions WHERE zones.name = 'B' AND elements.name = 'bcd' AND positions.name = 'yza';
```

I have a little more than 20,000 records and instead of executing thousands of sequential INSERTs each containing one SELECT, I was wondering if there was a way to execute a single INSERT containing all those SELECTs?

One thing that bothers me with on INSERT per SELECT is that I'm currently seeing the result of each INSERT independantly and if I do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM points;` at the end of the execution, I notice I'm missing *one* row in the database and I have no idea which one it is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, this join table is basically defining a three-level structure, i.e. zones containing elements containing positions.

Comment: An how do you know which elements belongs to which zone and which position belongs to which element if you don't properly join those three tables?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, those relationships are predefined by business rules and that's the role of this join table, but maybe I don't see the issue you're trying to make me be aware of here?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `values` clause and use an IN clause:

```
INSERT INTO points (zone_id, element_id, position_id) VALUES
SELECT zones._id, elements._id, positions._id 
FROM zones, elements, positions
WHERE (zones.name, elements.name, positions.name) IN ( ('A','abc','xyz'),
                                                       ('B','bcd','yta') );
```

But the cross join between the three tables looks really wrong to me.